# Split a String and store content into 3 different variable

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm able to split a string List very well, but I now want to put the content in 3 different variables accordingly in every loop.

It's a **List variable** that I use, but I just posted below one string to show the structure.

```
myString = "Toyota, Truck, 1996"

Dim var1, var2, var3 as String

Dim myString As String() = item1.Split(New Char() {","c})


Dim myValue As String

For Each myValue In myString

    Console.WriteLine(myValue)

Next
```

==

```
Result should be :

var1 = Toyota
var2 = Truck
var3 = 1996
```

Comment: If you do not want to put it into a container, you will have to do it by hand like `var1 = myValue(0) ... var2 = myValue(1)` and so on. Also, when doing like that always check if you have the expected number of elements in your array

Comment: I need to do that dynamically !! How do I put it in a container?

Comment: That would depend on the container. And the container to use depends on how you want to use the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
' List holding multiple strings
Dim myListVariable As New List(Of String) From {
    "Toyota, Truck, 1996",
    "Ford, Car, 1998",
    "Harley, Motorcycle, 1990"}
' Loop over each string
For Each myString In myListVariable
    ' Split each string into another List
    Dim myList = myString.Split({",", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    Console.WriteLine()
    ' assign to individual variables ...
    Dim var1 = myList(0)
    Dim var2 = myList(1)
    Dim var3 = myList(2)
    ' ... or iterate over items and print
    For Each myValue In myList
        Console.WriteLine(myValue)
    Next
Next
```

Output

> Toyota
>   
> Truck
>   
> 1996
>   
>   
> Ford
>   
> Car
>   
> 1998
>   
>   
> Harley
>   
> Motorcycle
>   
> 1990

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. Try this:

```
Dim myString As String() = item1.Split(New Char() {","c})
Dim Vehicle As String = myString(0)  
Dim Type As String = myString(1) 
Dim Year As String = myString(2)
```

EDIT 1: As you have commented you are using a `List(Of String)` variable, let's suppose `ListOfDetails` is the one in the question. Then

```
For Each detail as String In ListOfDetails
   Dim myString As String() = detail.Split(New Char() {","c})

   'Store values in variable like this if you want to
   Dim Vehicle As String = myString(0)
   Dim Type As String = myString(1)
   Dim Year As String = myString(2)
   'And print them using
   Console.WriteLine(Vehicle)
   Console.WriteLine(Type)
   Console.WriteLine(Year)

   'Else you can print them directly using this
   For Each myValue In myString
     Console.WriteLine(myValue)
   Next
Next
```

Comment: @Alice can you define _unexpected values_

Comment: @litelite Thanks for correcting me, my bad that i went with my C# instincts without checking the tag or codes for that matter

Comment: Thanks but mine is in a List Variable as I quoted above. I just used a string as example to show the type of string which is in the List.

Comment: @Alice can you update the question with the list variable as well, i'll update my answer accordingly